# PHP - file not sending to database error

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdo

I allow users to submit files into the database on my website. But every time a file is submitted, i get these error messages

```
( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\wamp64\www\MT\developerUpload.php on line 8

( ! ) Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp64\www\MT\developerUpload.php on line 9
```

But I was told that "file_get_contents" is the way you send the file contents to the database. Without the "file_get_contents" it sends perfectly but with it, it gives me those error messages and I am not sure why. So what i want to do is, submit the file using the "file_get_contents" so later on i can display the content on the users page. Here is my code

PHP

$query = "INSERT INTO pack_screenshots(pack_id, file_name, file_tmp)VALUES(:packid, :file_name, :file_tmp)";
             $stmtFileUpload = $handler->prepare($query);
             $errors = array();

```
         foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error){

             if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $errors[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
                continue;
            }

             $file_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            $file_name = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['name']));
             try{

                 $stmtFileUpload->bindParam(':packid', $packid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                 $stmtFileUpload->bindParam(':file_name', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                 $stmtFileUpload->bindParam(':file_tmp', $file_tmp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                 $stmtFileUpload->execute();

                 $dir = "devFiles";

                 if(is_dir($dir)==false){

                     mkdir($dir, 0700);
                 }

                 if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file_name)==false){

                     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$dir.'/'.$file_name);

                 }else{

                      $_SESSION['invalid'] = true;
                      header("Location: developer_invalid.php");
                      exit;
                 }

                 $_SESSION['thankyou'] = true;
                 header("Location: developerUpload_thankyou.php");
                 exit;
             }catch(PDOException $e){

                 $errors[] = $file_name . 'not saved in db.';
                 echo $e->getMessage();
             }
         }
```

Comment: It looks like you left NHL Jagr and now you want to learn PHP?

Comment: Yes :D I am a full time coder now :P

Comment: Which line is line 132/133? Please cut out the unimportant junk in your code block, we need a ***minimum* verifiable example**, not your lifes work., Cheers.

Comment: In your code, lines 132 and 133 are `$file_tmp = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));` and `$file_name = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['name']));` respectively. What is the output of `$_FILES['file']['name']`? If multiple files can be uploaded, that is your problem.

Comment: I do apologize for that. I edited the post ;D

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i fixed it to the correct codem and the output should be the file name but the problem is with the "tmp" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have no keys associated with the 2 lines giving you an error (and probably elsewhere in your code), therefore they are arrays (as you are not selecting a specific key).

You need to associate the keys to the $_FILES array.

```
$file_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key]);
$file_name = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['name'][$key]));
```

Comment: Ohhh i see why, but now my file isnt sending to the directory D: This whole code is messed up D:...

Comment: @Jagr That's a whole new question :)

Comment: LOLLL :P Thanks for the help, again :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using multiple uploads so you have to assign `keys` to them before proceed.

`file_get_contents()`  and `trim()` accepts string here you pass array in it without assigning key.

Try this:

```
$file_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key]);
$file_name = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['name'][$key]));
```

Comment: Thanks for copying my answer mate ^.^

Comment: What? I copied his question.

Comment: I'm not really accusing you of purposely stealing my answer, more accidentally. You're supposed to check if someone has already posted a similar answer when you have an answer. Basically, I posted the same answer before you - so yours doesn't add anything new to the thread

Comment: Yeah bro. My fault.. sorry !